# How to count for 2 different arrays how many times the elements are repeated, in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

I have array `A` (44x1) and `B` (41x1), and I want to count for both arrays how many times the elements are repeated. And if the repeated values are present in both arrays, I want their counting to be divided (for instance: value 0.5 appears 500 times in `A` and 350 times in `B`, so now divide 500 by 350).

I have to do this for bigger arrays as well, so I was thinking about using a looping (but no idea how to do it on MATLAB).

I got what I want on python:

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/data1.xlsx')
data2 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/data2.xlsx')

for i in data1['Mag'].value_counts() & data2['Mag'].value_counts():
    a = data1['Mag'].value_counts()/data2['Mag'].value_counts()
    print(a)
    break
```

Any idea of how to do the same on MATLAB? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ana, welcome to SO! In your example, "value 0.5 appears 500 times in A." What is the tolerance to be used when checking your floating-point data for unique values? In your example, how many times would `0.5` be considered to appear in the vector `[0.5 0.50001 0.6 7000]` ? One, two or three?

Comment: Hello! The tolerance is 0.1. So [0.5   0.6   0.7...]

Comment: Are all values exactly “0.6”, are they explicitly entered that way? Or are these the results of some computation, where many different floating-point results are all displayed as “0.6” because of the rounding in the display? Note that for example 0.1 cannot be represented exactly by a floating-point number, it is always an approximation.

Comment: Hey Cris, yes the values are exactly like this (they vary from 0.2 to 5.8, with a step of 0.1). It's a list of earthquakes magnitudes. So I need to find the repeated magnitude values in A and also in B and count their repetition. After that, everytime a repeated magnitude 'x' appear in A and in B, I want their repetition countings to be divided. I found the magnitude values that are common to A and B using intersect (A,B), but I don't know how to do something like: everytime a value appears in A and appears in B, divide their countings.

Comment: This is what I did , but is not very intelligent, because further I''ll have 9k data to do the same.                                                                                                                                
`a = data1(:,2);   %the second column is magnitude
 b = data2(:,2);

v=intersect(a,b)

ha=histc(a,v)
hb=histc(b,v)
%Ratio
r=ha./hb

E=[v,ha,hb,r] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can enumerate all valid earthquake magnitude values, you could use:

```
% Make up some data
A=randi([2 58],[100 1])/10;
B=randi([2 58],[20 1])/10;

% Round data to nearest tenth
%A=round(A,1); %uncomment if necessary
%B=round(B,1); %same

% Divide frequencies
validmags=0.2:0.1:5.8;
Afreqs=sum(double( abs(A-validmags)<1e-6 ),1); %relies on implicit expansion; A must be a column vector and validmags must be a row vector; dimension argument to sum() only to remind user; double() not really needed
Bfreqs=sum(double( abs(B-validmags)<1e-6 ),1); %same
Bfreqs./Afreqs, %for a fancier version: [{'Magnitude'} num2cell(validmags) ; {'Freq(B)/Freq(A)'} num2cell(Bfreqs./Afreqs)].'
```

The last line will produce NaN for 0/0, +Inf for nn/0, and 0 for 0/nn.

You could also use `uniquetol`, align the unique values of each vector, and divide the respective absolute frequencies. But I think the above approach is cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Why the *<= 0.049*? Thanks!

Comment: That's just slightly less than half the distance between two successive valid values. That way, 0.548 is counted as an instance of 0.5, 0.552 is counted as 0.6, and so on; values like 0.5491, 0.55, etc. are simply discarded. On second thought, that was an ugly design choice; you could probably use a much smaller tolerance, e.g. 1e-6, if necessary rounding numbers to the nearest tenth beforehand with `A=round(A,1)`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I got it, but the values were already rounded. It worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: No need to round them again, then! If this answer solved your problem, you can click the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted.